# Jquery: change child attribute in a post callback

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to change the value of a DOM child inside the POST success callback:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn_like', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        $(this).children('.nb_like').text('data');
    });
});
```

I don't know why this is not working! All I could think of is that the `this` variable could be different in the callback, but I don't know anything about Jquery so I don't know how to fix it!

If I put `$(this).children('.nb_like').text('data');` outside of the post then it's working fine so this is really the request that annoy me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a context variable:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn_like', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this);

    $.post($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
        that.children('.nb_like').text('data'); <--This appends the string of "data", remove the quotes if you want to append your callback data.
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice it's working! Could you explain me why the $(this) can't be used inside the callback?

Comment: Inside your post callback `$(this)` is now referring to the `$.post`, by defining a new variable before the post call (and assigning it `$(this)`, you can preserve the original context of `$(this)` and use it.